# Send SNMP trap using Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way we can send SNMP trap using JMeter? any plugin or we can do custom coding ? or we can develop the our own sampler

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [SNMP JMeter Plugin](https://github.com/intraway/iwaySnmpJmeterPlugin), according to its description:

   > SNMP JMeter plugin supports all the jmeter snmp calls
2. You can use any [SNMP Java Library](http://www.snmplink.org/software/fordeveloper/#8), for example [SNMP4J](https://www.agentpp.com/api/java/snmp4j.html) from [JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language and write whatever SNMP related code you want there

Comment: Above plugin not able to send the community name and not even the value.